# Retain namespace prefix in a tag when parsing xml using lxml

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

I have an xml as below. There are few tags which are prefixed with `ce` for example `<ce:title>`. When I run the code as below with xpath, in output, `<ce:title>` is replaced with `<title>`. I did see other links on SO like [How to preserve namespace information when parsing HTML with lxml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597271/how-to-preserve-namespace-information-when-parsing-html-with-lxml) but not sure where and how to add namespace details.

Can someone please suggest ? How can I retain `<ce:title>` for below xml?

```
from lxml import html
from lxml.etree import tostring
with open('102277033304.xml', encoding='utf-8') as file_object:
    xml = file_object.read().strip()
    root = html.fromstring(xml)
    for element in root.xpath('//item/book/pages/*'):
        html = tostring(element, encoding='utf-8')
        print(html)
```

XML:

```
<item>
    <book>
        <pages>
            <page-info>
                <page>
                  <ce:title>Chapter 1</ce:title>
                  <content>Welcome to Chapter 1</content>
                </page>
                <page>
                 <ce:title>Chapter 2</ce:title>
                 <content>Welcome to Chapter 2</content>
                </page>
            </page-info>
            <page-fulltext>Published in page 1</page-fulltext>
            <page-info>
                <page>
                  <ce:title>Chapter 1</ce:title>
                  <content>Welcome to Chapter 1</content>
                </page>
                <page>
                 <ce:title>Chapter 2</ce:title>
                 <content>Welcome to Chapter 2</content>
                </page>
            </page-info>
            <page-fulltext>Published in page 2</page-fulltext>
            <page-info>
                <page>
                  <ce:title>Chapter 1</ce:title>
                  <content>Welcome to Chapter 1</content>
                </page>
                <page>
                 <ce:title>Chapter 2</ce:title>
                 <content>Welcome to Chapter 2</content>
                </page>
            </page-info>
            <page-fulltext>Published in page 3</page-fulltext>
        </pages>
    </book>
</item>
```

Comment: The "XML" in the question is not really XML since there is no namespace declaration for the `ce` prefix (such as `xmlns:ce="http://example.com"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably caused by the fact that you are using an html parser to read xml.

Try it like this:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.XML(xml)
for element in root.xpath('//item/book/pages/*'):
        xml = etree.tostring(element, encoding='utf-8')
        print(xml)
```

This should give you the expected output.

Comment: This won't work. The `ce` prefix is not declared so the document in the question is not well-formed XML.

Comment: @mzjn True, I just assumed that there is a declaration in OP's actual xml. Maybe I should have made it explicit....

Comment: Yeah, I added tag `<item xmlns:ce="_">` to the xml and then instead of using html I used `etree.fromstring()` which fixed the issue.