# lxml ElementMaker Attribute formatting

Tags: python, attributes, lxml

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369329/python-adding-xml-schema-attributes-with-lxml) question/answer, I was able to get a namespace attribute added to a root element. So now I have this:

***Code***

```
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker

foo = 'http://www.foo.org/XMLSchema/bar'
xsi = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
E = ElementMaker(namespace=foo, nsmap={'foo': foo, 'xsi': xsi})

fooroot = E.component()
fooroot.attrib['{{{pre}}}schemaLocation'.format(pre=xsi)] = 'http://www.foo.org/XMLSchema/bar http://www.foo.org/XMLSchema/barindex.xsd'
bars = E.bars(label='why?', validates='required')
fooroot.append(bars)
bars.append(E.bar(label='Image1'))
bars.append(E.bar(label='Image2'))

etree.dump(fooroot)
```

This give me the desired output:

***Output***

```
<foo:component xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/XMLSchema/bar" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.foo.org/XMLSchema/bar http://www.foo.org/XMLSchema/barindex.xsd">
  <foo:bars label="why?" validates="required">
    <foo:bar label="Image1"/>
    <foo:bar label="Image2"/>
  </foo:bars>
</foo:component>
```

***The question***

Why does the `fooroot.attrib['{{{pre}}}schemaLocation'.format(pre=xsi)]` require 3 braces around the pre?

1 brace: `{pre}` causes a ValueError **BAD**
  2 braces: `{{pre}}` produces `ns0:schemaLocation` on the output **BAD**
  3 braces: `{{{pre}}}` produces `xsi:schemaLocation` on the output **GOOD**

I understand the `.format` usage for the string, but I'd like to understand why I need 3 braces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format of namespaced attribute name in `lxml` is `{namespace-uri}local-name`. So for `xsi:schemaLocation`, you basically want to add attribute with name:

```
'{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}schemaLocation'
```

The `{namespace-uri}` part can be achieved using `format()` and the triple opening and closing braces which can be read as:

- `{{`: escaped opening braces; outputs literal `{`
- `{pre}`: placeholder; will be replaced by the value of variable `xsi` as specified in `.format(pre=xsi)`
- `}}`: escaped closing braces; outputs literal `}`

Comment: Thank you for this Guess I didn’t understand the `.format` as well as I should.

Comment: Guess I didn’t understand the `.format` syntax as well as I should have.