# How to add different namespaces to node attributes in lxml

Tags: python-3.x, xml, lxml

I'm using `lxml` to generate an XML file such as the one below. The [documentation](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces) and other questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25132998/how-to-add-namespace-prefix-to-attribute-with-lxml-node-is-with-other-namespace), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405690/how-to-include-the-namespaces-into-a-xml-file-using-lxml)) here on Stackoverflow nudged me into the right direction. What I'm struggling with are namespace prefixes such as those in the `markList` and `mark` nodes.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!DOCTYPE paula SYSTEM "paula_mark.dtd">
<paula version="1.1">
    <header paula_id="Layer_Annotation.0_0000.mark"/>
    <markList xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" type="Annotation" xml:base="text.xml">
        <!--foo-->
        <mark id="span1" xlink:href="#sTok1"/>
        <!--bar-->
        <mark id="span2" xlink:href="#sTok2"/>
    </markList>
</paula>
```

This is what I got so far. As you can see from the output below, I'm stuck at the `markList` node, and have been banging my head at this for a while now. Any further nudges would be really appreciated.

```
from lxml import etree

class XMLNamespaces:
   xlink = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xml = "text.xml"

top = etree.Element("paula", {"version":"1.1"})
header = etree.SubElement(top, "header", {"paula_id": "annotation.mark"})
mark_list = etree.SubElement(top, "markList", {
    etree.QName(XMLNamespaces.xlink, "xlink"): "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink",
    "type": "Annotation",
    etree.QName(XMLNamespaces.xml, "xml"): "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink",
})

body = etree.SubElement(top, "body")    
body.text = "test body"
    
print(etree.tounicode(top, pretty_print=True))
```

Here is my current output:

```
<paula version="1.1">
  <header paula_id="annotation.mark"/>
  <markList xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ns1="text.xml" ns0:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" type="Annotation" ns1:xml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
  <body>test body</body>
</paula>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```
from lxml import etree
 
class XMLNamespaces:
   xlink = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xml = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
 
top = etree.Element("paula", {"version": "1.1"})
 
header = etree.SubElement(top, "header", {"paula_id": "annotation.mark"})
 
mark_list = etree.SubElement(top, "markList",
                             {"type": "Annotation",
                              etree.QName(XMLNamespaces.xml, "base"): "text.xml"},
                              nsmap={"xlink": XMLNamespaces.xlink})
 
mark = etree.SubElement(mark_list, "mark",
                        {"id": "span1",  
                         etree.QName(XMLNamespaces.xlink, "href"): "#sTok1"})
 
mark = etree.SubElement(mark_list, "mark",
                        {"id": "span2",  
                         etree.QName(XMLNamespaces.xlink, "href"): "#sTok2"})
    
print(etree.tounicode(top, pretty_print=True))
```

Output:

```
<paula version="1.1">
  <header paula_id="annotation.mark"/>
  <markList xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" type="Annotation" xml:base="text.xml">
    <mark id="span1" xlink:href="#sTok1"/>
    <mark id="span2" xlink:href="#sTok2"/>
  </markList>
</paula>
```

Comments:

- `nsmap={"xlink": XMLNamespaces.xlink})` on the `markList` subelement ensures that `xlink` and not `ns0` is used in the output.
- The URI for the `xml` prefix is http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace. This URI is a bit special since it does not need to be present in the XML file, but it must be used in the Python code.

Comment: Thank you! `xml = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"`, specifically, really solved  my main issue!